# Internal webcam not recognized by Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, updates, webcam

I'm pretty new to using Ubuntu. I just switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04. Mostly I work with developing software dealing with openCV applications. After getting visual studio set up and all of my libraries installed, I noticed that the camera does not turn on. I've been searching the forums and trying most of the solutions. I've tried enabling and disabling the camera in the BIOS menu and still does not work. In cheese, there is no option to select a device. And the listing of `lsmod` is below. Any help is very much so appreciated!

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  4
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 24576  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
btusb                  57344  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb 
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb 
bluetooth             548864  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
mei_hdcp               24576  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          53248  6
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
gpio_keys              20480  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm_intel             282624  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
aesni_intel           372736  4
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
mwifiex_pcie           45056  0
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
mwifiex               278528  1 mwifiex_pcie
rapl                   20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_timer              36864  3 snd_seq,snd_pcm
ipu3_cio2              36864  0
cfg80211              704512  1 mwifiex
i915                 1986560  20
snd                    90112  21 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
hid_multitouch         28672  0
hid_sensor_als         20480  1
8250_dw                16384  0
v4l2_fwnode            28672  1 ipu3_cio2
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     20480  0
hid_sensor_rotation    20480  0
hid_sensor_accel_3d    20480  1
soundcore              16384  1 snd
hid_sensor_trigger     20480  9 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  4 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
hid_sensor_iio_common    20480  5 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
videobuf2_dma_sg       16384  1 ipu3_cio2
industrialio           73728  9 industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_dma_sg
mei_me                 40960  1
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 ipu3_cio2
videobuf2_common       49152  2 ipu3_cio2,videobuf2_v4l2
mei                   106496  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
videodev              225280  4 v4l2_fwnode,ipu3_cio2,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_common
cros_ec_ishtp          20480  0
cros_ec                20480  1 cros_ec_ishtp
intel_xhci_usb_role_switch    16384  0
mc                     53248  4 videodev,ipu3_cio2,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_common
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
processor_thermal_device    24576  0
roles                  16384  1 intel_xhci_usb_role_switch
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
surfacepro3_button     20480  0
soc_button_array       20480  0
acpi_tad               16384  0
dptf_power             16384  0
int3403_thermal        20480  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
acpi_pad              184320  0
int3400_thermal        20480  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
sch_fq_codel           20480  5
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
drm                   491520  7 drm_kms_helper,i915
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_sensor_hub         24576  6 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_iio_common,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
intel_ishtp_loader     24576  0
intel_ishtp_hid        24576  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   131072  5 usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,intel_ishtp_hid,hid_generic
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
nvme                   49152  2
nvme_core             102400  4 nvme
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
idma64                 20480  0
intel_ish_ipc          24576  0
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
intel_ishtp            49152  4 cros_ec_ishtp,intel_ishtp_hid,intel_ish_ipc,intel_ishtp_loader
wmi                    32768  0
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  6
video                  49152  1 i915  
pinctrl_intel          28672  4 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
```

Comment: There is completely no information about hardware. Not all cameras are supported, etc.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the response. Given that it could be a hardware issue, is there any way I can install the proper drivers for it? I'm on my surface pro laptop which I switched to Ubuntu. I'd really hate to have to switch back to windows because of the camera not working.

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb`. That will show the device.